# Highlight if ANY of my drupal view results "Has New Content"

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a Drupal view that selects some nodes of a specific content type.
I use the "Has New Content" flag to highlight items that the user hasn't seen yet.

However I would like to put "*New*" in the heading if there is any content in the results that the user hasn't seen. (I dont even mind if the code goes in the footer as I can easily CSS it to where I want it!!)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple options:

1. Use an "attachment" display to tack on another view to your view, and pair it down so that it

   - Limits results to 1 row
   - Filters on only new content (so if nothing new the embedded view will display nothing)
   - Only displays 1 field from that one row
   - You rewrite that field to be the text "NEW CONTENT IS HERE!" (or whatever you want)
2. Insert a little bit of js code into your view header or footer (use a content filter that doesn't strip out `<script>` tags) that says something like (note I'm making these selectors up, use firebug to find out what they really are).

   ```
   jQuery(function($) {
     if ($('.new').length) {
       $('#view-header').append('<div>NEW CONTENT IS HERE!</div>');
     }
   );
   ```